# Has anybody measured the mass density profile $\Sigma = \Sigma (r)$ of a protoplanetary disk? (when $r<1$ AU)

Tags: radio-astronomy, star-formation, planetary-formation, proto-planetary-disk, radiative-transfer

I've been trying to find research articles where the mass density distribution $\mathrm{\Sigma = \Sigma(r)}$ is determined for protoplanetary disks, when $r<1$ au. For instance:

- [Here](https://www.aanda.org/articles/aa/pdf/2018/11/aa33595-18.pdf) A. Miotello, S. Facchini, E. F. van Dishoeck, and S. Bruderer use radiative transfer and submm data to probe the surface density distribution with $^{13}\mathrm{CO}$ emission.
- [Here](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.3847/0004-637X/830/1/32/pdf) Jonathan P. Williams and Conor McPartland measured density profiles with ALMA.

Seems like the method is similar. Despite that, I know that the available resolution in this band does not allow us to conclude much about the mass when $r < 1$ au. [ALMA's resolution](https://almascience.nrao.edu/about-alma/alma-basics) reaches $\sim 0.02''$ "in the most extended 12-m array configuration ($\sim \,16 \;\mathrm{km}$), when observing at $230 \;\mathrm{GHz}$.

**[TW Hydrae](https://aasnova.org/2016/04/11/featured-image-a-gap-in-tw-hydrae/)** is the nearest known protoplanetary disk. A(n "exquisite") resolution of $\theta \sim 3.5 \times 10^{-5}\;''$ would be needed to spatially resolve a diameter of $\mathrm{d_{TWH}} = 0.1 \;\mathrm{au}$.

[image: TW Hydrae]

**Questions**: Is it possible to measure $\Sigma$ at *this distances* ($d<0.1 \; \mathrm{AU}$)? Is there any work exploring on this? Are we limited mainly to models? (e.g., [Philip J. Armitage's Astrophysics of Planet Formation](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1107653088) textbook or [Jonathan P. Williams and Lucas A. Cieza](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1103.0556.pdf)'s review).

Comment: Those reviews should contain the info you want.... short answer is now, we can't measure the mass directly, because the bulk mass carrier ($H_2$) doesn't radiate actively at the low PP-disc temperatures. Instead one needs to link polar molecules, such as HD, CO, etc. via chemical modeling to the $H_2$ mass.

Comment: Has anybody ever done X? Here are two papers that do X.   I don't understand what you are asking

Comment: Hi @ProfRob My question is about the possibility to measure Σ at distances $d< 0.1$ au. I know that these two papers exist, but I don't know if that's the only known method... And I'm also not sure if reading J. Armitage, or Williams & Cieza's work will help me specificly with it.

Comment: I doubt we can do *experiments* on this... the scaling is aweful or the labs too small ;). We can observe, we can simulate it on the computer using numerics or we can model it ;)